# cannot convert from 'GoogleMobileAds.Api.InterstitialAd' to 'string'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

**I am getting This error :
Assets\Find The Pairs\Scripts\AdsManager.cs(54,43): error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'GoogleMobileAds.Api.InterstitialAd' to 'string'
with the following code :**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using GoogleMobileAds.Api;

public class AdsManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static AdsManager instance;

    private string appID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713";

    private BannerView bannerView;
    private string bannerID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111";

    private InterstitialAd fullScreenAd;
    private string fullScreenAdID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712";

    private void Awake()
    {
        if (instance == null)
        {
            instance = this;
        }
        else
        {
            Destroy(this);
        }
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        RequestFullScreenAd();
    }

    public void RequestBanner()
    {
        bannerView = new BannerView(bannerID, AdSize.Banner, AdPosition.Bottom);

        AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();

        bannerView.LoadAd(request);

        bannerView.Show();
    }

    public void HideBanner()
    {
        bannerView.Hide();
    }

    public void RequestFullScreenAd()
    {

        fullScreenAd = new InterstitialAd(fullScreenAd);

        AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();

        fullScreenAd.LoadAd(request);

    }

    public void ShowFullScreenAd()
    {
        if (fullScreenAd.IsLoaded())
        {
            fullScreenAd.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Full Screen Ad Not Loaded");
        }
    }

}
```

I am getting This error :
Assets\Find The Pairs\Scripts\AdsManager.cs(54,43): error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'GoogleMobileAds.Api.InterstitialAd' to 'string'

I need help plz

Answer (score 1):

```
public void RequestFullScreenAd()
    {

        fullScreenAd = new InterstitialAd(fullScreenAd);

        AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();

        fullScreenAd.LoadAd(request);

    }
```

You are trying to pass InterstitialAd Object as a string parameter when creating a new InterstitialAd Object. It requires an id (string) which is declared as fullScreenAdID. So,

```
public void RequestFullScreenAd()
    {

        fullScreenAd = new InterstitialAd(fullScreenAdID);

        AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();

        fullScreenAd.LoadAd(request);

    }
```

Should work.